# i cannot set select all checkbox to listview here is my code

Tags: android

Code for custome adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> name;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> group;

    boolean checkBoxState;

    public CustomAdapter( Context c,ArrayList<String> Cid, ArrayList<String> Cname,ArrayList<String> Cgroup) {
        this.name = Cname;
        this.id=Cid;
        this.group = Cgroup;
        MsgActivity msg=new MsgActivity();
        this.context = c;


    }





    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return id.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View Child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mholder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if(Child==null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            mholder = new Holder();
            mholder.txt_name = (TextView) Child.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_name);
            mholder.txt_Grp = (TextView) Child.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_group);
            mholder.txt_id = (TextView) Child.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_id);
            mholder.chk_box=(CheckBox) Child.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
            Child.setTag(mholder);
        }
        else
        {
            mholder=(Holder) Child.getTag();
        }
        mholder.txt_name.setText(name.get(position));
        mholder.txt_Grp.setText(group.get(position));
        mholder.txt_id.setText(id.get(position));
        mholder.chk_box.setChecked(true);







        return Child;
    }









    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_name;
        TextView txt_Grp;
        CheckBox chk_box;

    }
}
```

code for display activity

```
public class MsgActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    EditText tx1;
    TextView tv;
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    Spinner sp;
    ListView lv;
    String dat3;
    SQLiteDatabase dh;
    DbHelper mhelper;

    public Integer m=null;
    AddgrpActivity addgrp;
   public  CheckBox cb;

    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_name = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_num = new ArrayList<>();



    ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        dat3=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dat3,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_msg);
        tx1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2_add_msg);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_snd);
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mhelper = new DbHelper(this);
        cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);



        groups = addgrp.Addall();
        groups.add("all");
        ArrayAdapter<String> grps = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, groups);

        grps.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(grps);





        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                userId.clear();
                user_name.clear();
                user_num.clear();
                dh = mhelper.getReadableDatabase();


                Cursor mCursor;
                if (dat3 == "all") {
                    mCursor = dh.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

                    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                            user_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_NAME)));
                            user_num.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_GRP)));



                        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

                        CustomAdapter cst = new CustomAdapter(MsgActivity.this, userId, user_name, user_num);
                        //ArrayAdapter cst = new ArrayAdapter(MsgActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, user_name);

                        lv.setAdapter(cst);
                    }

                } else {
                    mCursor = dh.rawQuery("select * from " + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where " + DbHelper.KEY_GRP + " = ?", new String[]{dat3});


                    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                            user_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_NAME)));
                            user_num.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_GRP)));
                            lv.setChoiceMode(lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
                            //user_sal.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_SAL)));


                        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                    }

                }
                final CustomAdapter cst = new CustomAdapter(MsgActivity.this, userId, user_name, user_num);
                // ArrayAdapter cst=new ArrayAdapter(MsgActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,user_name);
                //lv.setChoiceMode(lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
                lv.setAdapter(cst);



                mCursor.close();


            }
        });


    }


            public void onBackPressed() {
                Intent in = new Intent(MsgActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        }
```

Comment: what is the result using this code?

Comment: you can set checked in xml if you want to set all checked

Comment: hwo can i add select all in list view by the help of a checkbox

Comment: @Nisarg i need to set select all by the help of independent checkbox

Comment: public void  setselect()
  {
      Holder mholder=new Holder();
      for(int i=0;i<=id.size();i++)
      {
          mholder.chk_box.setChecked(true);
      }
  } can i call this method by its object in main class?

Comment: @user3393818 it might be due to listview recycling view so use setonCheckedListener Refer here:-http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-checkbox-textview-listview/